# sympyのcoeffの使い方を教えて下さい

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
var('x a b')
f=a*(2*x**2 - 1) + 4*x**3 + x*(b - 3)
#次の行不要です。
#f=collect(expand(f),x)
print("#f＝#" ,f)
print("#3次#" ,f.coeff(x**3))
print("#2次#" ,f.coeff(x**2))
print("#1次#" ,f.coeff(x**1))
print("#0次#" ,f.coeff(x**0))
#f＝# a*(2*x**2 - 1) + 4*x**3 + x*(b - 3)
#3次# 4
#2次# 0
#1次# b - 3
#0次# a*(2*x**2 - 1) + x*(b - 3)
```

0次はaになりません。いい方法がありますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `p = Poly(f, x)` として、`p.coeff_monomial(x**0)` もしくは `p.coeff_monomial(1)` とします。

Comment: できました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(コメントより)

`p = Poly(f, x)` として、`p.coeff_monomial(x**0)` もしくは `p.coeff_monomial(1)` とします。