# sympy で与えられた2次関数に対して、原点からの接線の傾きを求めたい

Tags: python, sympy

今、 sympy で記述された2次方程式があるとします。

```
# 例えば、このような形で与えられる多項式、
# 実際のそれぞれの項の係数は、
# プログラムを実行してみるまでわからない
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
quad_poly = (x-10)**2 + 10
```

この `quad_poly` に対しての、原点からの接線の傾きを求めたいです。
「x についての2次方程式が重解になるような a を求めよ」
の関数があれば実現できると思うのですが、それが見つけられずにいます。
このような関数は sympy にありますでしょうか？

```
a = sp.Symbol('a')
finding_a_eq = quad_poly - a*x
# こんな関数はないでしょうか。。？
sp.find_double_root(finding_a_eq, x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sympyのcoeffの使い方を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33677/754) を参考に、 `Poly` と `coeff_monomial` を用いればすぐに実装できることに気づきました。

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
quad = (x-10)**2 + 10

def find_double_root(quad_poly_ish, var, solve_for):
    p = Poly(quad_poly_ish, var)
    a = p.coeff_monomial(var**2)
    b = p.coeff_monomial(var**1)
    c = p.coeff_monomial(var**0)

    determinant = b**2 - 4*a*c
    eq = Eq(determinant, 0)
    return solve(eq, solve_for)

a = Symbol('a')
arr = find_double_root(quad - a*x, x, a)

print arr[0].evalf()
print arr[1].evalf()

# => 0.976176963403031
# => -40.9761769634030
```

Answer (score 1):

sympyのcoeffを使わずにやってみました。結果がちょと違いました。

```
from sympy import *
var('x aa')
quad = (x-10)**2+10
line = aa*x
kekka=solve([Eq(quad,line), Eq(diff(quad,x),diff(line,x))])
print("# =>", float(kekka[0][aa]))
print("# =>", float(kekka[1][aa]))
# => 0.976176963403031
# => -40.976176963403034
```

Comment: なるほど、接線と2次曲線が等しくなることと、傾きが等しくなることの連立方程式として解いているのですね。2次曲線に限らず、任意の多項式に対して適用できそうです。