# sympyで,連立1次不等式の係数を取り出してみました。

Tags: python, sympy

①プログラムが短くなりますか？
②x,y,zにするためのアドバイスお願いします。

4*x+y <= 9,x+2*y >= 4,2*x-3*y >= -6  ----> Ax>=b
(参考)
[sympyのcoeffの使い方を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33677/sympy%e3%81%aecoeff%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e6%96%b9%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
def my_Str2Inequality(my_Str):
     if my_Str.find("<=") > 0:
          tmp = my_Str.split("<=")
          ans = sympify(tmp[1] + "-" + tmp[0])
     elif my_Str.find(">=") > 0:
          tmp = my_Str.split(">=")
          ans = sympify(tmp[0] + "-" + tmp[1])
     else:
          ans=""
     return ans
def my_xykeisu(my_Pol2):
     f = symbols('f', cls=Function)
     f = sympify(my_Pol2)
     my_ans0=f.coeff(x**1)
     my_ans1=f.coeff(y**1)
     p = Poly(f, [x,y])
     my_ans2=p.coeff_monomial(x**0)
     my_ans=[my_ans0,my_ans1,my_ans2]
     return my_ans
my_inequality=['4*x+y <= 9','x+2*y >= 4','2*x-3*y >= -6']
my_Str=my_Str2Inequality(my_inequality[0])
my_list0=my_xykeisu(my_Str)
my_Str=my_Str2Inequality(my_inequality[1])
my_list1=my_xykeisu(my_Str)
my_Str=my_Str2Inequality(my_inequality[2])
my_list2=my_xykeisu(my_Str)
A=Matrix([my_list0,my_list1,my_list2])
print("#",my_inequality)
print("#",A)
# ['4*x+y <= 9', 'x+2*y >= 4', '2*x-3*y >= -6']
# Matrix([[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]])
```

Comment: 「x,y,zにする」とはどういう意味でしょうか。

Comment: 3元連立1次不等式の意味でした。'4*x+y+z <= 9', 'x+2*y-z >= 4', '2*x-3*y +z>= -6'。xyの時は、3角形以上?n角形を作る。xyzの時は、四面体以上?m面体を作る。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
def my_Str2Inequality(my_Str):
     if my_Str.find("<=") > 0:
          tmp = my_Str.split("<=")
          ans = sympify(tmp[1] + "-" + tmp[0])
     elif my_Str.find(">=") > 0:
          tmp = my_Str.split(">=")
          ans = sympify(tmp[0] + "-" + tmp[1])
     else:
          ans=""
     return ans
def my_xykeisu(my_Pol2):
     f = symbols('f', cls=Function)
     f = sympify(my_Pol2)
     my_ans0=f.coeff(x**1)
     my_ans1=f.coeff(y**1)
     p = Poly(f, [x,y])
     my_ans2=p.coeff_monomial(x**0)
     my_ans=[my_ans0,my_ans1,my_ans2]
     return my_ans
my_inequality=['4*x+y <= 9','x+2*y >= 4','2*x-3*y >= -6']
my_num=len(my_inequality)
mylist=[[0]*my_num]*my_num
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(my_num):
    mylist[i]=my_xykeisu(my_Str2Inequality(my_inequality[i]))
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i, Matrix([mylist[i]]))
print("#",my_inequality)
print("#",myMatrix)
# ['4*x+y <= 9', 'x+2*y >= 4', '2*x-3*y >= -6']
# Matrix([[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]])
```