# sympyのMatrix.row_insertの使い方を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy, 行列

以下のエラーがでました。
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cols'
以下のように出力する方法を教えて下さい。
Matrix([[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]])

```
from sympy import *
var('myMatrix')
mylist=[[0]*3]*3e
mylist[0]=[-4, 1, 9]
mylist[1]=[1, 2, -4]
mylist[2]=[2, -3, 6]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i-1, mylist[i])
print("# ",myMatrix)
```

(参考)
[sympyで,連立1次不等式の係数を取り出してみました。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75142/sympy%e3%81%a7-%e9%80%a3%e7%ab%8b1%e6%ac%a1%e4%b8%8d%e7%ad%89%e5%bc%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%bf%82%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bf%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f)

Comment: どの行でエラーが発生したのでしょうか？

Comment: myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i-1, mylist[i])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row_insert`でlistを挿入しようとするとエラーが発生します。
下記のように2か所を書き換えるとうまく行くはずです。

```
from sympy import *
var('myMatrix')
mylist=[[0]*3]*3  # FIX
mylist[0]=[-4, 1, 9]
mylist[1]=[1, 2, -4]
mylist[2]=[2, -3, 6]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i, Matrix([mylist[i]])) # FIX

print("# ",myMatrix)
```