# sympyでlistとMatrixの相互変換をやってみました。Matrix→list変換を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

①Matrix→list変換を教えて下さい。
②Matrix→list変換。list→Matrix変換。それぞれ1行で書けますか？
よろしくお願いします。
(参考)
[sympyのMatrix.row_insertの使い方を教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75475/sympy%e3%81%aematrix-row-insert%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e6%96%b9%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

```
from sympy import *
mylist=[[0]*3]*3
mylist[0]=[-4, 1, 9]
mylist[1]=[1, 2, -4]
mylist[2]=[2, -3, 6]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i, Matrix([mylist[i]]))
print("# mylist  ",type(mylist))
print("# mylist  ",len(mylist),mylist)
print("# myMatrix",type(myMatrix))
print("# myMatrix",len(myMatrix),myMatrix)
mylist2=[[0]*3]*3
for i in range(sqrt(len(myMatrix))):
     for j in range(sqrt(len(myMatrix))):
          # print(myMatrix[i,j])
          mylist2[i][j] = myMatrix[i, j]
print("# mylist2 ",type(mylist2))
print("# mylist2 ",len(mylist2),mylist2)
# mylist   <class 'list'>
# mylist   3 [[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]]
# myMatrix <class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>
# myMatrix 9 Matrix([[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]])
# mylist2  <class 'list'>
# mylist2  3 [[2, -3, 6], [2, -3, 6], [2, -3, 6]]
# mylist2がおかしいです。
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(参考)【Python】多次元配列に値を代入するときの注意点
https://qiita.com/oyoshi0022/items/7475951f465d20ad4970

次のコードの5行目mylist=[[0]*3]*3が、あやしいと思います。

```
from sympy import *
var('a11 a12 a13')
var('a21 a22 a23')
var('a31 a32 a33')
mylist=[[0]*3]*3
mylist[0]=[a11, a12, a13]
mylist[1]=[a21, a22, a23]
mylist[2]=[a31, a32, a33]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i, Matrix([mylist[i]]))
print("# mylist  ",type(mylist))
print("# mylist  ",len(mylist),mylist)
print("# myMatrix",type(myMatrix))
print("# myMatrix",len(myMatrix),myMatrix)
# mylist2=[[0]*3 for i in range(3)]
mylist2=[[0]*len(mylist) for i in range(len(mylist))]
for i in range(len(mylist)):
     for j in range(len(mylist)):
          mylist2[i][j] = myMatrix[i, j]
print("# mylist2 ",type(mylist2))
print("# mylist2 ",len(mylist2),mylist2)
# mylist   <class 'list'>
# mylist   3 [[a11, a12, a13], [a21, a22, a23], [a31, a32, a33]]
# myMatrix <class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>
# myMatrix 9 Matrix([[a11, a12, a13], [a21, a22, a23], [a31, a32, a33]])
# mylist2  <class 'list'>
# mylist2  3 [[a11, a12, a13], [a21, a22, a23], [a31, a32, a33]]
```